# Copy few columns from one CSV to another CSV using java based on column name(header)

Tags: java, csv

I have to copy few columns (with all its data about 36k+) from one csv to another csv based on column names.

I have tried below thing but getting arrayoutofbound exception:

```
    String csvSplitter = ";";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFileName, "UTF-8");
    String line = "";

    String[] cols = line.split(csvSplitter);
    List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(cols);
    System.out.println(cols[columns.indexOf("ID1")]);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        /*output.println(cols[1] + csvSplitter);

         * for (int i = 1; i <= colNumtoCopy; i++) { output.println(cols[i]);
         * output.print(csvSplitter); }
         */

    }
```

Comment: a) what do you think would happen if there is not String in the columns list with the value `ID1` ?  b) you are reading the next line if the loop but never using it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am getting the excpetion at sysout only and hence have not updated the while loop. Also String is there in the mentioned column

Comment: Digressing a bit from your code - rather than manually parsing CSV, I think you should use some library like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). It will make it easy for you to read CSV and write to another CSV. It will also have an added advantage of handling special characters

Comment: @Smile I have tried the same for reading data from database and writing it to excel using     writer.writeAll(myResultSet, includeHeaders);      method. But I am not able to apply the same logic for csv to csv thing. Need help

Comment: Before doing `System.out.println(cols[columns.indexOf("ID1")]);` do `System.out.println(line);` - lets see the output